# ERR INSECURE RESPONSE from nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, node.js

I am experiencing something weird. I have a webserver that is running Linux. It has a NodeJs expressjs application and has a Nginx server managing its certificates and reverse proxying the traffic received from my Angular frontend to the http url which is my Nodejs API.

When i run my application the server is recognized by Chrome and i can load the site but as soon as i try to make a request from the front end (login) and it goes through Nginx to the api it returns a Err insecure response.

Here is a snippit of my Nginx setup.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/angular;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/cert.cer";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/certs/cert.key";;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    #API for Reverse proxy to ExpressJS

    #Login
    location /auth
    {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth;
    }
```

When i call an API get function directly form the url in chrome it actually returns the response.

Is there some headers i might have to add in my application or something i have to add to the Reverse proxy setup ?

This was working perfectly before i implemented the HTTPS. The certificate is valid though and working as intended. Any idea what could cause this?

Thanks in regards

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504827/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response-socket-io), the issue may be related to the certificate chain of the certificate exposed by nginx.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out, i called the API using the IP in the application but the certificate is installed on the DNS so you must use the DNS name.